# SQL data has unwanted line breaks?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a script that is somehow inserts line breaks into the end of the data that is being inserted in SQL.  I don't see anything in the script that is adding a line break.

Is there a way to strip all line breaks inside the INSERT statement?  I can't imagine what could be doing this.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the quick answers guys.  I ended up using the php trim function right before the data insert - that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Apply `TRIM()` mysql function to the needed fields.

```
INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (TRIM('foobar'))
```

where `foobar` is your data.

But better I would suggest to find why that script adds those newlines.

Comment: Hmm..  I just tried that and it didn't work.  Seems like it should.